# Создание php-"демона"

Tags: php

Появился ли удачный способ запуска php-скрипта, который будет постоянно в памяти, а раз в какое-то время выполнять некоторое действие?

Answer (score 4):

Никогда не было проблем запускать PHP скипты под *nix'ами в режиме демона. Однако, практически никто так не делает по простой причине - память в PHP течет. Течет как из решета.

И проблема тут не столько в циклических ссылках (это как-раз частично решается в PHP 5.3 при помощи [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)) и плохой работой с памятью во внутренних структурах (в основном этим грешат сторонние расширения), сколько в идеологии языка.

В PHP, в отличии от всех остальных популярных языков, время жизни скрипта крайне мало, т.к. каждый вызов скрипт выполняется каждый раз *с нуля в новой среде окружении*. Соответственно, при таком коротком цикле утечки памяти и не заметны, и не критичны. Что не скажешь про долгоиграющих демонов, где даже небольшая утечка сможет стать большой проблемой.

По этому я бы рекомендовал все же выбрать более подходящий язык для написания демона. Благо выбор велик: python, ruby, perl, java, erlang или native c, наконец :)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно [вот эта](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/134620/) статья поможет вам.

Comment: IMHO довольно безумная идея писать такие штуки на PHP. Может лучше C поучить ?

Comment: Пусть пишет на том что знает, php так то хороший язык, не вижу в нем чего то кардинально делающего его хуже всяких С

Comment: @Стас Казанин, сделайте замеры времени и особенно памяти, требующихся для решения одной и той же задачи на C и PHP. 

Думаю Вы сильно измените свое мнение.

Comment: Скажем прямо, я не осведомлен, по личному опыту скажу что C# и Java крайне прожорливы до памяти, а php, а что php, ему надо то, компилятор в 10 мегабайт)

Comment: @Стас Казанин, вот честно, осведомитесь и не позорьтесь.

Comment: Согласен с @avp, на крайняк, демон можно сделать на perl

Answer (score 0):

На линукс хосте есть планировщик задач, CRON, ему по условию/таймеру пожно задать запуск php срипта, так все делают, инфа 100%)

Comment: Вот только демоном это никто не называет.